# Condition for polynomial to have repeated real roots.

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Using Rolle's theorem find the condition  that a polynomial equation $f(x)=0$ can have repeated real roots.

And hence using this condition prove that  $1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}\dots +\frac{x^n}{n!}$ cannot have repeated real roots.

Comment: if $r$ is a repeated root, then $r$ is a root of $f(x)/(x-r)$

Comment: consider a and b on either side of the repeated root such that f(a)=f(b). So, by Rolle's theorem, there must exist c in (a,b) such that f'(c)=0. Now, since f(x) has a repeated root, the repeated root will also be a local maxima or minima of the polynomial as it satisfies f'(x)=0. Which implies one of the solutions for f'(c) is the repeated root itself. In short, the polynomial and its derivative will have the repeated roots as the common zeros.

Comment: @ShankRam if the repeated root is like this : [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pEFh6.png) in this case it is neither local maxima nor minima and neither derivative vanishes, so what to do?

Comment: write the polynomial as $(x-x_1)^m$(x-$x_2$)... (x-$x_n$). Then clearly, the derivative will vanish at $x_1$.

Comment: Here's a related thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070913/prove-that-fx-0-has-no-repeated-roots